# How to set Pin touch mode to capacitive on micro:bit v2 in MicroPython

Tags: touch, micropython, bbc-microbit

If I use the makecode editor to create the code, it generates:

`pins.touch_set_mode(TouchTarget.P0, TouchTargetMode.CAPACITIVE)`

However, if I try and run this, it can't find 'pins'.

Note: I then investigated further and found out how to do this before submitting my question...

Comment: Note: I just found the same detail as my answer below in the docs at https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/v2-docs/tutorials/io.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitive mode can be set for each pin, e.g.

```
from microbit import *
...
pin0.set_touch_mode(pin0.CAPACITIVE)
...
if pin0.is_touched():
    ...
```

The last line checks whether the pin is touched - usually in a loop.

Hope this saves other people some time...